# PHP - CSS Not being read if I navigate to a url

Tags: php

My website uses URL Segments to have dynamic pages.
I basically load in content of php files instead of redirecting to them.
Everything works fine, navigate to a second URL segment the CSS doesn't get loaded.

Allow me to elaborate:
**mydomain.com/foo** loads "*root/somedirectory/foo/index.php*" into my `<body>` in my main index.php.

**mydomain.com/foo/bar** loads "*root/somedirectory/foo/bar.php*" into my `<body>` in my main index.php

The problem is: When I go to the second URL (With bar in the URL) the CSS from the main index.php doesn't get loaded anymore and the console gets spammed with errors.

This is odd because it has basically the same logic as when I don't add bar (thus loading index.php).

**Errors:** http://oi68.tinypic.com/148pzec.jpg

My code (main index.php)

```
if(!urlSegment(1)) include("home.php");
else{
    $target = strtolower(urlSegment(1));
    $targetFolder = FILE_PATH.$target."/";
    $fileName = !urlSegment(2) ? "index.php" : strtolower(urlSegment(2)).".php";
    $fileTarget = $targetFolder.$fileName;
    if(file_exists($fileTarget)) include($fileTarget);
    else{
        echo 'Page not found ('.$fileTarget.')';
    }
}
```

The urlSegment function simply gets the part of the url as a string.
If you have "*www.stackoverflow.com/foo/bar/donut*" foo = 1, bar = 2, donut = 3

Thanks in advance!

**AFTER EDIT**
The full (main) index.php looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Bunch of CSS / Javascript Links -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php /*php The code above */ ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

"bar.php" basically has normal HTML in it that will be included in the `<body>` tags. It uses styling from the CSS links in the `<head>` tag.
Keep in mind that one URL Segment works like a charm, a second one will break it.

This popped up in the console for every .css file: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Folder Structure seen through console when I navigate to ONE URL segment (**like it should**):
http://oi64.tinypic.com/2qwmpuo.jpg

Folder Structure seen through console when I navigate to TWO URL segments (**like it should NOT**):
http://oi67.tinypic.com/2lo3tl4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your code is a mystery, but as a quick fix -try something like this:

```
$path = (explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))[0];  // request path
$mime = array_pop((explode('.', $path)));  // file extension

if ($mime == 'php')
{
    // ... your code here
}
else
{
    if (!is_readable($path))
    {
        $fail = 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found';
        header(!file_exists($path) ? $fail : 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        exit;
    }

    ob_get_clean(); // clear output buffer that could cause issues

    header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');

    // ... send appropriate headers here, according to mime & size

    readfile($path);
    exit;
}
```

The idea is to simply "serve" any other file that is not a "php" file.

---

#### Update

The "fix" above will help isolating conditions in handling different file-types.

The errors shown in the image could be caused by a PHP error amidst the JavaScript output and this could also be causing the CSS not showing up as expected.

Comment: I don't see how this would fix it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but it seems as if though your logic tries to run on all file-types; so, encapsulating your logic in a condition that only works on "php" files, and just "serves" other files, (like CSS, or HTML, or fonts & images) could work... even so, this is just an example, modify and use it wherever it is necessary, or appropriate in your code.

Comment: If i'm completely wrong, kindly update your question and share more of your code and explain the process flow as it will help understanding what is wrong.

Comment: The answer is updated, even so, to debug your code, try commenting out your PHP code, and step by step un-comment it accordingly. This will help isolating the problem.

Comment: I updated my question once more, I found a strange occurrence in the console regarding the folder structure in both URL's

Comment: I can't help debugging your application, however, please mark answers if they are relevant or helpful, or vote them accordingly. If your debugging experience leads to another question, open a new question and answers can commence accordingly. thanks